# How to know if multiple checkbox in form is checked or not and insert the value in database table c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-express

I want to insert value in database table for each checkbox (1 if checked and 0 of not checked).

I put all checkbox's in a groupbox.

I hope that there is a way to do it with a loop because I there is so many checkbox

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source =.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = sales_sys; 
Integrated Security = True");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = /* insert sql statement*/ ;

int x =0;

DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
tbl.Clear();
tbl.Columns.Add("value");

foreach (Control c in groupBox1.Controls)
{
    if (c is CheckBox)
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)c;

        if (cb.Checked == false)
        { x = 0 ;}
        else
        { x = 1;}

       tbl.Rows.Add(1);
       int index = tbl.rows.count - 1;
       tbl.rows[index][0] = x;
    }
   
    conn.Open();
    tb.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    conn.Close();
```

I want to insert the date in database table in one row like the following

- (first datatable row = second database table column)
- (second datatable row = third database table column)
- (third datatable row = forth database table column)

and I make sure that the table rows are equal to the number of checkbox's

and how to do the reverse process like the following for all first row columns .

- If second column in the table is 1 then change first checkbox to checked
- If second column in the table is 0 change first checkbox to unchecked

and going on until the end of the columns.

Comment: are you using a `checkedlistbox`  for your check boxes ?

Comment: No .. I use normal `checkbox` in a `groubox` .. I can change it to a `checklistbox` if that's the easiest way ..

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `checkedlistbox` mycheckedlist and then use

```
private void savemychecks()
{
    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
    tbl.Clear();
    tbl.Columns.Add("value");
    foreach (object item in mycheckedlist.Items)
    {
        if (mycheckedlist.CheckedItems.Contains(item))
        {
            tbl.Rows.Add("1");
        }
        else
        {
            tbl.Rows.Add("0");
        }
    }          
}
```

This is since I don't know what else is in your database table and what columns you have there, if you add those to your question I can update my answer.

Comment: Thank you..  my database table contains only  a column for each checkbox

Comment: @AhmedMohammed are you using any ORM ? like dapper ?